# how get text codenumber Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

html

```
<div style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333; font-weight: bold"><span id="BodyPlaceholder_UserVerificationEmailBodySentence2">Your code is: 601103</span></div>
```

how to get text code 601103
python

```
x=driver.find_element_by_id('BodyPlaceholder_UserVerificationEmailBodySentence2').text
```

not work i need help

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the span element by xpath using the id then keeping the code number only:

```
code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="BodyPlaceholder_UserVerificationEmailBodySentence2"]').text.split("is: ")[1]
```